# Appcelerator - Add widget into tableviewrow

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have a `tableView` and I want to add a `widget` into a `tableViewRow` by code in the js file.

My widget is called: "es.comboBox" (I'm using it in other controllers and it works perfectly, but I'm creating it at xml file).

This is my code:

**index.xml**

```
...
<TableViewRow id="row_subseccion" layout="vertical"</TableViewRow>
...
```

**index.js**

```
var widget = Alloy.createWidget("es.comboBox", {
    choices: subsecciones,
    value: -1
});

$.row_subseccion.add(widget);
```

The **error** is: (The error appears when the program is executing the add instruction)

> libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x76616a64 (code=1), thread 5058
>   (KrollRuntimeThr)

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

This works, but I need to add it after an action from the user.

```
<TableViewRow id="row_subseccion" layout="vertical">
        <Widget src="es.comboBox" class="selectField" id="subseccion"></Widget>
</TableViewRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `widget` var holds the actual Alloy Controller of the widget, not the view you can add to the row. Please change to:

```
$.row_subseccion.add(widget.getView());
```